# the Android libraries to Ubuntu system

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, android, compiling, libraries

Hello How can I add the Android libraries to Ubuntu system, in order to run Android applications without the use of the emulator

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible.

Comment: y not !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: In your question, you have the tags "12.04", "lubuntu", and "compiling", but it is not mentioned in your question. Perhaps you want to add more information about your system, and whether or not you want to compile Android applications on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041470/is-it-possible-to-run-an-android-emulator-without-setting-up-eclipse) link will answer your question.
Still you are not clear about your question.

> Do you want to run android application in your Ubuntu PC?

If yes, then you have to compile application for x86 to run on your PC instead of cross compiling it for android device.
And about compiling application without SDK you can use NDK by writing android makefile.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.